# Notepad ++ Moving one line to the start of the next line

Tags: notepad++

I have thousands of lines in notepad++ where a person's title and initials are in one line and the surname in the next. I am trying to get this all into one line. There is also other info on lines inbetween so I can't just merge every 2nd line. This is what is looks like:

MRS M B
XXXXX

I need it to be MRS M B XXXXX.

Is there some way I can search for "MRS" and move that line to the start of the next line?

Comment: “Moving to the second line” is quite a wrong phrasing. What you _can_ do, is to remove/replace the line break character(s) between the two lines, thereby making them one line. N++ is capable of replacing using regular expressions – but you have to find one first. And therefor you need to be specific about what distinguishes those “wrong” lines from the right ones. Is simply _every_ line that begins with `MRS` to replace?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

Find what: `(MRS.*?)\R`
Replace with: `$1`

`\R` stands for any line break.

Comment: You probably want to replace with `$1 ` (note the space after `$1`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're into trying other editors - try [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) and do the following:

```
<Ctrl+F> // search in file
MRS
<Alt+Enter> //multi-select all
<End><Space><Delete> // to concatenate the two lines
```

It works pretty fast for ~20000 lines.